# Simulating Hover On Touch Screen Devices Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which makes a link active on the 2nd tap when using touch screen devices.

Code adapted from:

[hnldesign.nl](http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/)

(function($) {

```
var landingLink = '.nav-landing > li';

if (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)) {

    // DISPLAY LANDING PAGE MEGA NAV ON TOUCH
    $(landingLink).live('touchstart', function (e) {

        var link = $(this);
        var megaDiv = $(this).find('div');

        // REMOVE touch-device CLASS IF NAV LINK HASN'T BEEN TAPPED
        if (!megaDiv.hasClass('touch-device')) {
            $('.touch-device').removeClass('touch-device');
        }

        if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
            // SECOND TOUCH
            return true;
        } else {
            // FIRST TOUCH
            link.addClass('hover');
            megaDiv.addClass('touch-device');
            $(landingLink).not(this).removeClass('hover');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }); 
}
```

})(jQuery);

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bradford6/m5y72/)

I'm attempting to set it so that a div element with the class .touch-device displays next to the link when it is tapped (1st tap) but I'm having issues removing the .touch-device class if another link is then tapped. I can't figure out how to target the div in order to remove the class 'touch-device'.

An example of my code can be found at:

I would really appreciate some help in solving this issue.

Comment: not most optimized but why not just `$('.touch-device').removeClass('touch-device');` before adding it to specific element???

Comment: That looks to have worked. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Almost works but when I tap a link within the touch-device div it closes (removes the touch-device class) rather than opening the page link. I've updated my jsfiddle to display a link within the touch-device div

Answer (score 0):

Just remove touch-device class from whole tags from your html code. Add this line at the first line of your function:

```
$('.touch-device').removeClass('touch-device');
```

Comment: Almost works but when I tap a link within the touch-device div it closes (removes the touch-device class) rather than opening the page link. I've updated my jsfiddle to display a link within the touch-device div.

Comment: I've now fixed the issue by adding an if statement around the touch-device class. (see updated code above)